# Safari input type search reset/normalize

Tags: css

Is there a official way on how to reset a search input to make it look the same as a text field in Safari?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GPUg.png)

Safari is adding some annoying padding to the left side which I can't remove.

```css
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" value="abc"><br>
<input type="text" value="abc">
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

```css
input {
  padding: 0;
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="search" value="abc"><br>
<input type="text" value="abc">
```